# discord.py channel.history returning object "Context" han no attribute 'id'

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```py
    @bot.command(cls = CommandWithCooldown, pass_context = True)
    @commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def strikeball(message, yy=None):
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0xeee657, inline = False) #created embed
        embed.set_author(name = message.author, icon_url = message.author.avatar_url)
        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        embed.set_footer(text = 'BotSiniy© | {}'.format(today.strftime("%H:%M %d/%m/%Y")))
        if yy==None:
            embed.add_field(name = 'Команда: strikeball',  #description command
            value = "**Описание:** Начинает игру в strikeball(перестрелка)\n**Cool:** 1 сообщения за 30 секунд\n**Использование:** `s!strikeball start`")
            await message.channel.send(embed = embed)
        elif yy=='start':
            red=[]
            blue=[]
            await message.channel.send('Игра начнется через 60 секунд.... Для присоединения используйте `join (red или blue)`')
            for x in range(1,6,1):
                time.sleep(10)
                await message.channel.send('Игра начнется через {} секунд.... Для присоединения используйте `join (red или blue)`'.format(int(60-(x*10))))
                chat_history = await message.channel.history(limit=10, after = message).flatten()
            for msg in chat_history:
                if msg.author in red or msg.author in blue:
                    pass
                else:
                    if msg.content== "join red":
                        red.append(msg.author)
                        ping = msg.author.mention
                        await message.channel.send(ping+',присоединился к красной команде!')
                    elif msg.content=='join blue':
                        blue.append(msg.author)
                        ping = msg.author.mention
                        await message.channel.send(ping+',присоединился к синей команде!')
            time.sleep(10)
        if len(red)<1 or len(blue)<1:
            await message.channel.send("Недостаточно пользователей для начала игры...")
```

Eroor:

> Ignoring exception in command strikeball:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "bot.py", line 243, in strikeball
> async for msg in message.channel.history(limit=10,after = message):
> File "C:\Users\Trava\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
> es\discord\iterators.py", line 91, in **anext**
> msg = await self.next()
> File "C:\Users\Trava\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
> es\discord\iterators.py", line 285, in next
> await self.fill_messages()
> File "C:\Users\Trava\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
> es\discord\iterators.py", line 331, in fill_messages
> data = await self._retrieve_messages(self.retrieve)
> File "C:\Users\Trava\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
> es\discord\iterators.py", line 360, in _retrieve_messages_after_strategy
> after = self.after.id if self.after else None
> AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'id'
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Trava\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
> es\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
> await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
> File "C:\Users\Trava\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
> es\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
> await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Trava\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
> es\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
> raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Att
> ributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'id

problem in after, but i dont understand why.
Please help me

Comment: can you give us a bit more details on your code and the hole error message

Comment: @Guddi . i make

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument in a command is always `commands.Context`, short `ctx` 
You named it `message` wich is confusing because its still the `commands.Context`, not a `discord.Message`, as you can see in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) `'Context' object has no attribute 'id'` which is also the error

So first rename that:

```py
# old
async def strikeball(message, yy=None):
# new
async def strikeball(ctx, yy=None):
```

If you want the commands message which is a `discord.Message` you can use [`ctx.message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.message)

```py
@bot.command()
async cef strikeball(ctx, yy=None):
    message = ctx.message
```

Now also `await message.channel.history(limit=10, after=message).flatten()` should work